# How to remove multiple folders with given pattern from repository index?

Tags: git

I need to remove multiple folders following a given pattern "/0.*".

The command

```
git -rm -r -cached <dir>
```

works fine for a single folder. See also https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm.

But if I am trying

```
git rm -r  --cached  0.*/
```

I get the following message

```
fatal: pathspec '0.01/' did not match any files
```

**How do I correctly parse the pattern `0.*/` to the `git rm`  command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to quote the asterisk so that the shell does not expand it but git can handle it

```
git rm -r  --cached  0.\*
```

Comment: That's it. Thank's a lot! One small adjustment is needed:
`git rm -r --cached  0.\*`
works without the slash at the end of the line.

Comment: I have adapted the answer.